# Run Zend Framework with a temporary URL

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I'm working on an application using Zen Framework, the application is running correctly in one server but I have to move it to a different (shared) hosting, is it possible to run zend framework with a temporary url?

By temporary url I refer to something like this: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username

If so, could you share an .htaccess that makes this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a redirect using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Create a file in your init folder: **.htaccess** and put the code above